# Let $A = \left[ \begin{matrix} I & X \\ 0 & -I \end{matrix} \right]$, $X\in\mathbb R^{m\times n}$ arbitrary. Need to show value of $e^A$.

Tags: linear-algebra, sequences-and-series, matrix-exponential

> Let $A = \left[ \begin{matrix} I & X \\ 0 & -I \end{matrix} \right]$, $X\in\mathbb R^{m\times n}$ arbitrary. Need to show value of $e^A = \left[ \begin{matrix} eI & \sinh 1X \\ 0 & \frac 1 e I\end{matrix} \right]$.

We know that $A^2 = I$ and $A^k = \begin{cases} A \quad &k\text{ odd} \\ I & k\text{ even}. \end{cases}$ for $k = 0, 1,\dots$. A plausible solution is so far
$$
\begin {split} e^{A} &= \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac 1{k!}A^k \\ &= \left[ \begin{matrix} \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac 1{k!}I & \sum_{k\text{ odd}} \frac 1{k!}X \\ 0 & \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac { (-1)^k}{k!}I \end{matrix} \right] \\ &= \left[ \begin{matrix} eI & \frac 12\left(\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac 1{k!}X - \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac {(-1)^k}{k!}X\right) \\ 0 &  \frac 1eI \end{matrix} \right] \\ &\vdots \\ &= \left[ \begin{matrix} eI & \sinh 1X \\ 0 & \frac 1 e I\end{matrix} \right].\end{split}
$$

**Note:** The '$\vdots$' part is easily follows recognizing the power series expansion of $e^x$. What I don't understand is the following string of arguments in the upper right block regarding $X$ matrix. That is how does this work:
$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac 1{k!}X = \sum_{k\text{ odd}} \frac 1{k!}X = \frac 12\left(\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac 1{k!}X - \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac {(-1)^k}{k!}X\right).$$

**EDIT:** I understand the last equality now considering the power series expansion of $\sinh$. Now I just need clarification on going from LHS to RHS:
$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac 1{k!}X = \sum_{k\text{ odd}} \frac 1{k!}X $$

Any help is appreciated thanks!

Comment: $X\in \mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$?

Comment: I don't understand your question @xpaul.

Comment: X is a matrix with m rows and n columns.

Answer (score 2):

$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty{1\over k!}A^k = \sum_{k\text{ even}}{1\over k!}I + \sum_{k\text{ odd}}{1\over k!}A$$

Answer (score 1):

$ e^{A}=\sum \limits_{\underset{}{k=0}}^\infty \frac{A^{k}}{k!}= \sum \limits_{\underset{k  Odd}{k=0}}^\infty \frac{A}{k!} + \sum \limits_{\underset{k  even}{k=0}}^\infty \frac{I}{k!}.$

$\frac{1}{2}(e^1-e^{-1})= 
\frac{1}{2}(\sum \limits_{\underset{}{k=0}}^\infty \frac{1}{k!}- \sum \limits_{\underset{}{k=0}}^\infty \frac{(-1)^k}{k!} )\\= \sinh(1) \\=\frac{1}{2}(2\sum \limits_{\underset{k  odd}{k=0}}^\infty \frac{1}{k!})\\= \sum \limits_{\underset{k  odd}{k=0}}^\infty \frac{1}{k!}.$

Comment: Ok, do you know how we go from LHS to RHS in the expression: "$\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac 1{k!}X = \sum_{k\text{ odd}}\frac 1 {k!}X$" (in my original post at the bottom?

Comment: This equality is false.

Comment: We do not need the left member.

Comment: Ok, that would make sense. Then considering this expression: "$e^A = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac 1{k!}A^k = \left[ \begin{matrix} \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac 1{k!}I & \sum_{k\text{ odd}} \frac 1{k!}X \\ 0 & \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac { (-1)^k}{k!}I \end{matrix} \right]$", how does it get the right upper block in the matrix?